# build of my local project in eclipse is failed without any error?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created a local java project in eclipse and trying to build the same using maven.I am not getting any error or exception but still build is getting failed.
[image]

Thats how i am creating build of project:

And that is the log I am getting:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HBaseTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.077 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-19T17:39:15+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "test" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "tesy". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Comment: There is an error : `Unknown lifecycle phase "tesy"` , could you provide your pom.xml (or the relevant parts) ?

Comment: Its getting failed when I am building in eclipse, but build was success when I used CMD i.e 
projectpath > maven clean install